# XAML Gridview not rebinding on RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, mvvm, observablecollection

EDIT: This is a Windows Store (8.1) application

I have a person class as shown below which I am using as a model

```
public class Person : BaseModel
    {
        private string _FirstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _FirstName; }
            set
            {
                if (_FirstName == value)
                    return;

                _FirstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }

        private string _MiddleName;
        public string MiddleName
        {
            get { return _MiddleName; }
            set
            {
                if (_MiddleName == value)
                    return;

                _MiddleName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MiddleName");
            }
        }

        private string _LastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _LastName; }
            set
            {
                if (_LastName == value)
                    return;

                _LastName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
    }
```

where BaseModel is defined as below

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
public class BaseModel: ObservableObject
{
}
```

I am using the Model in a ViewModel class as shown below.

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// List of searched People
        /// </summary>
        private ObservableCollection<Person> _People;
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People
        {
            get { return _People; }
            set
            {
                if (_People== value)
                    return;
                _People= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("People");
            }
        }
}
```

I am binding the People collection to a GridView as shown below.

```
<GridView
                        x:Name="PeopleSearchResultsGridView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
                    </GridView>
```

When the search completes I get back a list of people which I add to the list as follows.

```
var list = await p.SearchPeople();
People = new ObservableCollection<Person>(list);
```

I see that the setter for the People collection is firing and the RaisePropertyChanged("People") event is also firing however that is not updating the GridView. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here ?

Comment: where are you setting the UI's `DataContext`?

Comment: Yes, doing that in the View's constructor. ViewModel = new PersonViewModel ();
this.DataContext = ViewModel;

Comment: Found the issue: Was doing the following in XAML >.< (did it some time ago when I was binding controls) <Grid.DataContext>
            <ViewModel:PeopleViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>